# Exception Class in C++ not functioning

Tags: c++

I'm a student in the process of learning C, I am trying to make a user defined exception class. I watched a few videos and read a few tutorials and ended up with this program. However every time I try to run the program and throw the exception the program closes and I get the fallowing message with the option to change some settings.

> Unhandled exception at 0x75BF1812 in EC1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: FileNotFound at memory location 0x0073F4BC. occurred

I tried to look up this message but I didn't find anything. Any advice on how to move forward or what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

class FileNotFound : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what()
    {
        return ("Exception: File not found.\n");
    }
};


const int NO_OF_COMPUTES = 2;

struct computerType
{
    std::string cID;
    std::string manufacturer;
    std::string name;
    std::string cpuSpeed;
    int ramSize;
    double price;
};


void getComputer(std::ifstream& infile);

/*void writeComputer(ofstream& outfile, computerType list[],
    int listSize);*/


int main()
{

    std::ifstream infile;    //input file stream variable
    std::ofstream outfile;   //output file stream variable

    std::string inputFile;   //variable to hold the input file name
    std::string outputFile;  //variable to hold the output file name





    computerType computerTypeList[NO_OF_COMPUTES];

    std::cout << "Enter the input file name: "; 
    std::cin >> inputFile;                               
    std::cout << std::endl;

    infile.open(inputFile.c_str());                 

    if (!infile)
    {
        FileNotFound a;
        throw a;
    }

    getComputer(infile);


    infile.close();                                 
    outfile.close();                              
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getComputer(std::ifstream& infile)
{
    int index;
    std::string cID;
    std::string manufacturer;
    std::string name;
    std::string cpuSpeed;
    int ramSize;
    double price;

    infile >> cID;
    while (infile)
    {
        infile >> manufacturer >> name >> cpuSpeed >> price;
        std::cout << cID << " " << manufacturer << " " << name << " " << cpuSpeed << " " << price;
        infile >> cID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you catching the exception? What result did you expect by throwing the exception?

Comment: `what` is only called if you call it in a `catch` block.  Not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: The error message is merely saying that a "FileNotFound" exception was thrown and not caught, and doesn't have a message.

Comment: Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of watching videos and tutorials - they're not worth the money you're paying for them.

Comment: You can cut down your example to `int main() { throw FileNotFound();}`. Perhaps that makes it clearer what's (not) happening.

Comment: @molbdnilo most of them are not worth the money even if they come for free ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, that was my point.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::exception::what`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) has the signature:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
```

Yours misses the `const` qualifier: you're not overriding it. It should be:

```
struct FileNotFound : std::exception
{
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return "Exception: File not found.\n";
    }
};
```

**But** it won't solve your problem: you're not catching the exception. If a non handled exception is thrown in `main` (among other situations like stack unwinding), `abort()` is called and your system may print an helper message like yours does. You need to [document yourself about exceptions in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).